# One Source code target multiple platform ( desktop , android , ios )

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I have done lot of codding in c++ and has some basic idea about html ,css and JavaScript.

Now I am developing web application using node.js and react.js .

The user of my application can use from web browser and mobile both .

Can I develop single application targeted to all like

- Run on web browser
- Generate native app from same application ( apk and ios)

Did some research and found that if I develop using below framework desktop compatibility is missing .

https://ionicframework.com/

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have an app in Node and React, I think your best bet would be [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/). It will work on both android and ios, but it's not a "native" app - it uses webview to show your webapp, in js, html and css.

If you want a native app created in javascript, take a look at [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) - however you can't easily transfer from an already existing webapp in react. It is possible though, to create a React Native app that shares code with a webapp with this package: [React Native For Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)

Answer (score 2):

How about MeteorJS https://www.meteor.com/
For Desktop compatibility I guess you could integrate it with Electron http://electron.atom.io/

Comment: meteor does not work on my Linux system and seems like not suitable for large complex application . Electron is for desktop app .

Comment: Meteor works on linux just fine, and it is suitable for any kind of application

Comment: Can you share steps to do for Windows

Answer (score 1):

Try cordova phonegap , you can add it to Eclipse Android IDE

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

But if you use WebView , you will get slow performance and aspect-ratio issue on some devices.

Also you can use cordova phonegap but you will get same performance with WebView(but it supports to use camera,microphone from js code)

->You can use Crosswalk's WebView to solve that issues.(But it will take 20-25 mb in your apk)

I think you should develop native apps with NativeScript or React-Native.

The last and best solution is developing real-native apps with java and obj-c or swift but if you don't have any time issues.

http://www.nativescript.org

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

update from december of 2018 :

I highly recommend Google's Flutter for anyone who wants to one source code target multiple platform (android and ios)

https://flutter.io/